# How can I make leiningen 2 respect the local repository path in maven's settings.xml file?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Leiningen 2 doesn't seem to use the localRepository setting in my ~/.m2/settings.xml file, it just dumps everything it downloads into ~/.m2/repository regardless.

How can I tell leiningen 2 where to download stuff to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override the local repository location for an individual project in the project.clj file like this

```
(defproject test-local "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Use a local repo location."
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [com.cemerick/pomegranate "0.0.13"]]
  :local-repo "my-repo")
```

It is possible to set a relative path under the project directory as above or an absolute path.  It doesn't seem to be possible to use a shortcut for the home directory and set this to something like "~/my-repo".

You can make all projects use the same location by adding the key to your profiles.clj file.

```
{:user {:plugins [[lein-swank "1.4.4"]]
        :local-repo "/home/jeff/my-repo"}}
```